# Is there an early termination option in the parallel processing function (such as future_apply) in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using the future.apply package in my R code to do parallel processing on 100 Monte-Carlo Simulations on an optimization problem.

For now let's assume that the output of the optimization for each simulation is either **True** (optimal solution found) or **False** (no optimal solution found). Can I set up condition(s) so that if the first 10 simulations return False, the parallel process will be terminated?

**EDIT :** I include a small example below - can I terminate this after 10 runs?

```
library(future.apply)

plan(multiprocess)
outputs <- future_lapply(1:100, function(i){
  temp <- FALSE
  return(temp)
})
```

Comment: @MrFlick: Thanks for your comment. I added a small example

Comment: The last I saw on this topic was from the maintainer: "Termination of futures is currently not supported by the Future API. This is something that needs to be implemented in the future package before anything can be done higher up. Getting a consistent API for terminating futures is not easy because it depends on the backend used." from https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.apply/issues/60

Comment: It is also counter to "normal flow" in `lapply` (non-`future`), which will always attempt to apply the `FUN` to all elements of `x`, even if unnecessary.

Comment: {author of future/future.apply here}: This is a good question and feature request. 
 What you're basically asking for is something like `break` we have for `repeat()`, `while()` and `for()` loops.  I've got it on my internal todo list to look into this, e.g. a `return_break()` or `break_and_return()` which would give you a way of say, "This, this is what I was looking for - no need to do anything more; everything else can take value NA, NULL, ...".  Whether it fits into the "lapply" model or it should be something else, needs to be figured out - not really specific to parallelization.

Comment: Continuing... As others have said, for this to be efficient in parallel processing, we need a mechanism to terminate tasks/workers no longer needed.  That is on the roadmap and will be implemented first.  BTW, `future_either()` [non-existing] that I mention in 'Other uses of futures' of https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/article-bengtsson-future is closely related to this, or possibly even exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikB for your reply - IMHO this is really a feature of having workers communicate with the overhead as the job is complete. A relevant feature request that I saw is the ability to track progress (such as 38/100 complete).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediary file in which you write the result of each simulation. Each time a new simulation is launched, you check if the first 10 results are FALSE and if yes, you ask the thread to kill itself. `future_lapply()` must be used inside a `try()` wrapper because the function will obviously fail.

```r
library(future.apply)
library(tools)

func <- function(i){
  tbl_results <- read.csv("results.csv")
  results <- tbl_results[, 2]
  
  if(length(results) >= 10 & all(results[1:10] == FALSE)) pskill(Sys.getpid())
  
  result <- FALSE
  
  cat(paste0(i, ",", result, "\n"), file = "results.csv", append = TRUE)
  return(result)
}


plan(multiprocess)
cat("input,result\n", file = "results.csv")
outputs <- try({future_lapply(1:100, func)}, silent = TRUE)

if(!is.list(outputs)) stop("10 first simulations returned FALSE")
```